# VERIFICAR REGISTROS DE UMA TABELA SECUNDÁRIA, ATRAVÉS DO id DA TABELA PRINCIPAL

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

***Nessa questão a tabela principal em questão é denominada 'fin_main' , e a tabela secundária é a 'fin_detalhes'.***

Exemplo do Script das tabelas : ( Não é o original )

```
CREATE TABLE `fin_detalhes` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fin_main_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `fin_modalidade_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_fin_mov_x_modalidade_fin_mov1` FOREIGN KEY (`fin_main_id`) REFERENCES `fin_main` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=218417 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `fin_main` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fin_operacao` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'C - Credito\nD - Debito',
  `dt_emissao` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `numero_documento` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=200079 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

### O que eu preciso?

Saber SE ESTÁ FALTANDO ALGUM registro na tabela 'fin_detalhes'.. que no caso seu 'id' vai estar constando apenas na tabela 'fin_main'.

Se for para verificar 1 'id' por vez , eu consigo usando o `select if`. Ex:

```
select if 
(exists ( select * from fin_detalhes where fin_main_id is not null and fin_main_id = 10
), 'ESSE id EXISTE', 'ESSE id NÃO EXITE')
```

**Porém preciso de ajuda para fazer de alguma maneira que seja mais eficaz! que não seja 'id' por 'id' ..**

ps: usando o 'IN' EX: `fin_main_id in (10,20)` NÃO DEU CERTO TAMBÉM!

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Posta o código de criação das tabelas.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar `left join` para verificar se existem dados em uma tabela mas não existe na outra.

Basta verificar no `where` se algum campo not null da tabela do left join é nulo.

Um exemplo: https://www.devmedia.com.br/clausulas-inner-join-left-join-e-right-join-no-sql-server/18930#3

Parte importante do texto do link acima: "A cláusula LEFT JOIN ou LEFT OUTER JOIN permite obter não apenas os dados relacionados de duas tabelas, mas também os dados não relacionados encontrados na tabela à esquerda da cláusula JOIN. Caso não existam dados relacionados entre as tabelas à esquerda e a direita do JOIN, os valores resultantes de todas as colunas da lista de seleção da tabela à direita serão nulos."

```
select m.* from fin_main as m 
left join fin_detalhes as d
    on m.id = d.fin_main_id
where d.fin_main_id is null
order by m.id
```